# {% url %} tag add twice the localized prefix in django

Tags: python, django, localization, django-views, url-routing

With Django version 1.5.dev17942 I have this setup:

settings.py:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',

    #'maintenancemode.middleware.MaintenanceModeMiddleware',
)
```

With urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Api
    url(r'^api/bestSeller/', include('apps.pluginApi.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)

urlpatterns += i18n_patterns('',
    # Core:
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='home'),
    url(r'teleport/signup/(?P<plan>\w+)', views.teleport_signup, name="teleportSignup"),
    url(r'teleport/account$', views.teleport_account, name="teleportAccount"),
    url(r'teleport/login$', views.teleport_login, name="teleportLogin"),
    url(r'teleport', views.teleport, name="teleport"),
)

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

When I use the template tag:

```
{% url 'teleportSignup' 'teleportplan1' %}
```

I get this url:

> /es/es/teleport/signup/teleportplan1

Note that is twice "es". The initial URL (that render the page) is `/es/teleport`.

I can't see what is causing this. Or how avoid it..

Comment: Is this because of the i18n_patterns prefix you are using. 

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#django.conf.urls.i18n.i18n_patterns

Django would add the language prefix ?

Comment: The prefix are added by django itself, then twice for the url tag.

Comment: Can you try one thing?  url(r'^teleport .. for all the URLs? This could throw 404 if there are any mistakes.

Comment: With that generate the same URL, and get a 404 when clicked. Removing it, the url is the same but it found the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was something really stupid. I have a dependency in https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-localeurl, carried from the old project. This was ALSO generating locale urls, so the reason to have it twice...